# tcpdump shows traffic even for down interface

Tags: debian, security, firewall, iptables, tcpdump

Using Debian Buster and having configured VLAN interface online, I wonder that `tcpdump` shows any traffic send to the external IP address?

Having a server on Hetzner and want to configure VLAN traffic only. The server is configured for VLAN and only the VLAN interface is up. So I SSH into a firewall and then SSH on the internal VLAN interface.

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0.4000
iface eth0.4000 inet static
  address 192.168.0.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  mtu 1400
```

The server has in addition external IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

When using `tcpdump` I will see incoming traffic / packets to the server while `ifconfig` only shows eth0.4000 as active network device.

Is that a security issue and how to block incoming packets on a down interface?

Actually there is no respond from server outside the VLAN, just incoming packets.

Comment: OK. I added this to the question, so you can delete the comment (space is limited). But the server does have IP interfaces (IP addresses) in public IP ranges, visible over the internet, right? Same still applies - even if the interface is inactive but there's a route to it over the internet, someone will always come knocking. If the interface is down, I don't see how it could pose a security risk, but if you're concerned you could maybe ask Hetzner to drop any ingress traffic towards the public IPs already on the routers.

Comment: Thanks @Peregrino69 - Exactly that was the question: "Is it normal to see others knocking even when the iface is down but - yes -  there's a route to it over the internet! As far I got from your comment: It is normal, and no concern about it. Should I add for security an `iptables -A INPUT|FORWARD -i eth0 -j DROP`?

Comment: I expanded this to a full answer. Sorry mate, I'm not well-versed in with `iptables`, but if I read that correctly that's the "deny all" rule I mentioned.

Comment: Yes - it is - DENY ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. The internet is full of bad actors. Every public IP interface is continuously bombarded with attempts to gain access. These attacks have a few common features:

- They usually target port 22 (SSH), tho' other common remote access ports are also attempted
- There's a number of attempts originating from a single IP address
- `nslookup` etc. show these IP addresses belonging to a hosting company, usually located in countries well-known as attack sources
- The attack from a single address lasts only for a short time
- After the attack completes it's very rarely repeated from the same IP address
- Authorization logs show login attempts for users like root
- A single username attempts to login using multiple different passwords

This happens with all devices, including home routers. These are simple bruteforce attacks done by bots using wordlists. While malicious, these attempts are easily prevented by following simple rules:

- Don't allow remote root access; or disable root access entirely and use `sudo` when necessary for system maintenance
- Ensure firewall's running and stays  up-to-date
- Basic firewall rule "drop all ingress packets unless explicitly allowed bu other rules" should be always present as the last line of a firewall ruleset. I tend to add this even if the FW solution has an implicit deny.
- Open ports for ingress traffic only when necessary; and open only the necessary ports
- Employ only well-established secure access methods such as SSH or VNC
- Use non-standard ports for remote access

There are a few things that can be done to add extra layers of security:

- Configure SSHD to only listen to requests on the IP interface(s) in active use
- Use [Fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or similar to block a specific IP address for a time after certain number of failed login attempts
- To simplify administration drop IPv6 support entirely on the host, if it's not actively used
- Ask the hosting provider to drop ingress traffic to your public IPs already on their routers

If the interface is down, there's really no way for these attempts to succeed; so it can be argued these extra methods are redundant. However it can also be argued that there is no such a thing as "too much security" - unless the applied security measures start to hamper your own ability to act.